# Derivatives of quotients (rate of change)

Tags: derivatives

PRODUCT RULE ONLY 
A function modelled $D(t)=.5(t^2+8)(t+4)$ where t is years from now. Find the rate of change when $D(t)=756$

I did most of the work already bringing 756 to the other side and getting the function $t^3+4t^2+8t-1480$ I know that $(t-10)$ is a factor and that the other two are messed up other things. I have no idea what to do afterwards though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calculate the derivative of the function $D(t)$ using the product rule:

\begin{align}
\frac{dD(t)}{dt} =& \; 0.5\left(\frac{d(t^2+8)}{dt}(t+4)+(t^2+8)\frac{d(t+4)}{dt}\right)\\
=& \; 0.5\left((2t)(t+4)+(t^2+8)(1)\right) \\
=& \; 0.5\left(3t^2+8t+8\right) \\
\end{align}

Next, calculate $t$ when $D(t)=756$, that is solve

$$ 0.5(t^2+8)(t+4) = 756 $$

for $t$, which which has only one real solution: $t=10$.

Finally, solve for the derivative (which is the rate of change) at $t=10$,

\begin{align}
\frac{dD(10)}{dt} =  0.5\left(3(10)^2+8(10)+8\right) = 194.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First find $t$ when $D(t)=756$
$$756=.5(t^2+8)(t+4)$$
$$0=.5(t^2+8)(t+4)-756$$
$$0=.5(t^3+4t^2+8t-1480)$$
$$0=.5(t-10)(t^2+14t+148)$$
and since $t^2+14t+148$ has no real solutions the only solution would be $t=10$. Now find $D'(10)$
$$\frac{dD}{dt}= \frac{d}{dt}(.5(t^2+8)(t+4))=\frac{d}{dt}(.5t^3+2t^2+4t+16)=1.5t^2+4t+4$$ evaluate at $t=10$ we get
$$D'(10)=1.5(10^2)+4(10)+4= 194$$
Thus $D'(10)=194$

Comment: I supposed I didn't use the product rule but same idea just take the derivative differently.